# Maven clean install Failed (Illegal char <:> at index 76:)

Tags: java, maven

I tried to execute `mvn clean install` command in cloned repository from git. But I got this error message while executing above command.

**Illegal char <:> at index 76: C:\Users\PC.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\maven-metadata-https:\sss.jfrog.io\resolver-status.properties**

I tried to download dependencies in pom.xml file.

Comment: Looks like you've got a badly named file. What does `dir 'C:\Users\PC.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\maven-metadata-https:\sss.jfrog.io\resolver-status.properties'` give you?

Comment: There is no file on this path.

Comment: I would be tempted to search for the string or the plain last part of the file name (resolver-status.properties) but that's really just investigative. Someone here might know what's actually behind this problem

Comment: Does the issue persist? That file might have been removed since then by git or Maven. Based on the error it was there at some point and was most likely malformed.